How can we compare the "performance" of different Markov chain Monte Carlo algorithms?
How can we judge the performance a Markov chain Monte Carlo (MCMC) algorithm? I guess we could consider one of the following:

The variance of $X_t$ for a given $t\in I$;
The asymptotic variance of $(X_t)_{t\in I}$;
The "distance" between $\mathcal L(X_t)$ and $\pi$  for a given $t\in I$;
The rate of the convergence of $\mathcal L(X_t)$ to $\pi$ as $t\to\infty$

Here $(X_t)_{t\in I}$ is the Markov process being simulated by the algorithm, $I=\mathbb N$ or $I=[0,\infty)$, depending on whether we simulate a discrete- or continuous-time process, and $\pi$ is the target distribution.
In 3. and 4. I would also like two know which distance metric (total variation norm, Wasserstein distance, ...) is usually chosen. I think in 3. and 4. we could also consider the distance/doncergence of the estimate to $\int f\:{\rm d}\pi$ for a fixed integrand $f$.
I'm especially interested in comparing different MCMC algorithms and in comparing different parameters of a given MCMC algorithm$^1$. How do I approach these comparisons in practice? Both, theoretically and empirically? What has been done in the literature so far?
Any help and indication is highly appreciated!

$^1$ For example, if the MCMC algorithm is the Metropolis-Hastings algorithm, we could compare different proposal kernels. Or if the proposal kernel is a Gaussian perturbation, we could compare different scalings (which has been done in Roberts "optimal scaling" paper(s)).
